# R, Shiny and reactive for subsetting dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I have a pretty simple app (I thought), but I can't make it work. The reactive part is kinda working, but I cannot use `x1` in my plot expression. Getting:

```
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
```

Here is my ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Count Report "),
    h4("This application shows product data"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectizeInput("product","Product:",c("ALPHA","BRAVO","all"), selected="all")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          h4("Chart "),
          h4(textOutput("pr")),
          plotOutput("chart")

        )
    )
))
```

And server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {
      x <- data.frame(PRODUCT=factor(c("ALPHA", "ALPHA","BRAVO","ALPHA","ALPHA")), 
                      YYYYMM= factor(c("2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015","6/1/2015")),
                      COUNT=c(44,22,37,76,97))

      ## select only rows where PRODUCT = input$product
      x1 <- reactive({
        x[ ( x$PRODUCT == input$product   | input$product == "all") , ] 
      })

      output$pr <- renderText(input$product)

      output$chart <- renderPlot({
          #hist(x$COUNT)
          hist(x1()$COUNT)
        })
})
```

Comment: Above code is working and am not getting any error.Tell me where are you running RStudio on web browser or as desktop version??

Comment: Tx, Ars, I'm on most recent Rstduio on laptop, after runnapp if I use that x1() I'm having an error. So you able to get diff hist? If so I'll try to use it on anoher machine

Comment: Try to run rstudio as admin

Comment: Thanks, Ars. It worked!!!!